# Why the difference of two measures is a signed measure?

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\mu_1: \mathcal{M} \to [0,\infty)$ be a finite measure and $\mu_2: \mathcal{M} \to [0,\infty]$ be a measure (can take infinite value).

Now define $\mu: \mathcal{M} \to [-\infty,\infty]$ by $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$. I want to show $\mu$ is a signed measure.

The conditions "$\mu(\emptyset)=0$" and "$\mu$ can only take either $\infty$ or $-\infty$" is clear (in this case $\mu$ takes $-\infty$).

I need to show for any {$\{E_k\}$} is a countable collection of disjoint measurable sets, we have
$$\mu \Big( \bigcup_k^{\infty} E_k \Big) = \sum_k^{\infty} \mu(E_k).$$

I decide to split into two cases:

1. $\mu \Big( \bigcup_k^{\infty} E_k \Big)$ is finite. I managed to prove this case.
2. $\mu \Big( \bigcup_k^{\infty} E_k \Big) = -\infty$. If there exists some $k_0$ such that $\mu(E_{k_0}) = - \infty$, then we have the equality. But the problem is when every $\mu(E_k)$ is finite. In this case, $\mu_1(E_k)$ and $\mu_2(E_k)$ are also finite for every $k$. How to show $\sum_k^{\infty} \mu(E_k) = -\infty$?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Actually I read Royden and Fitzpatrick's textbook:
[image]
So I just want to take an example.

Comment: Note that if the measure is $-\infty$ that it is unbounded. That can't be said for the finite measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k}E_k\right)=\mu_1\left(\bigcup_{k}E_k\right)-\mu_2\left(\bigcup_{k}E_k\right).$$

Using disjointness, this equals

$$\sum_k\mu_1(E_k)-\sum_k\mu_2(E_k)=\sum_k(\mu_1(E_k)-\mu_2(E_k))=\sum_k\mu(E_k).$$

Comment: In your example, $\mu_1(E_k)=2$ and $\mu_2(E_k) = \infty$. So, $\mu(E_k) = -\infty$.

Comment: @FactorY Sorry, I misdefined the $E_k$. I fixed it now.

Comment: I still have one question: How do you know that $\mu_2$ is a measure?

Comment: @FactorY See "Definition and properties" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure.

Comment: Why would we expect summability on sets that are not disjoint?

Comment: @Dunham I missed that. Added that my answer only proves that disjointness is necessary...

Comment: @FactorY Sorry, for some reason I missed disjointness. But with it, the proof is straightforward and needs no separation of cases.

Comment: @Zuy: That's not correct.  Our problem is when we rearrange the terms in our series, it may become divergent or finite (the first inequality).

Comment: @FactorY I don't see the problem here. We know that the first series is finite (because $\mu_1$ is finite) and the second one is either finite or infinite (the latter in the case you are missing). You can take both series together with no problem.

Comment: You can only take linear combination of two series if they are both convergent.

Comment: @FactorY If one of them is convergent, it also works. :) Let me add a proof.

Comment: @Zuy: I have realized it too, :) Maybe I make everything complicated.